# Ruby/regex_ extracct text from PDF

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, pdf

I am parsing a bunch of PDF files using Regex with Ruby, to extract the date from every file, below my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pdf/reader'
reader = PDF::Reader.new("works.pdf")
reader.pages.each do |page|
var= page.text
puts var.scan(/^(?<=31C: Date of Issue\n)([^\n]+$)/)
end
```

Having the same structure for all pdf files (content is text, structured with  fields), my code sometigmes extracts the text (so works well), sometimes not, and I can't figure out why;
what am I missing ?
Here the two files ( deleted all confidential informations)  [my 2 files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_NqyVKsVKbza3dJdU8xRHlZa3M&usp=sharing)
- the file "works" is the one on which the code works
- the file "not.pdf" is the on which the code doesn't work

Many thanks

Comment: I cannot copy the text in your PDFs. Most probably the issue is that whitespace differs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Don't put necessary data in a link; Links rot then break, resulting in a question that lacks necessary supporting information, which won't help anyone in the future.

Comment: Thank you. Just to precise, I considered enclosing the 2 files necessary, because scraping the text extracted from the PDF (from example using regex101.com) was successful, I faced my issue only when I treat the PDF files; Many thanks

Comment: In cases like this supplying sample files indeed is a good thing to do. That being stated, have you considered simply inspecting the contents of `var`, especially for the not-working sample file?